# fetch substring from string between two special character like ^abc^ in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form with 2 textboxes and command button. What I want to do in VBA is to copy part of text from `text1` to `text3` when `cmd` button pressed. For example part of the string `#&!4848484848484 ^totot/euhen^ gjrlsmdkkkd` in `text1` to be copied to `text3` is `totot/euhen`, so there is no fixed numbers or places before, somehow it has to be predicated on the `^` symbol. I.e. `text3` = whatever is between `^` and `^`.

Comment: `Split(text, "^") (1)`

Comment: @omegastripes Write it up as the answer as that would do it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `Split` function, add the below code to the user form:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim aTmp
    aTmp = Split(TextBox1.Value, "^", 3)
    If UBound(aTmp) = 2 Then TextBox3.Value = aTmp(1)
End Sub
```

That code splits source text by `^` character and puts the parts in array. The array length is limited to 3 elements, having indexes 0..2. So the sample string `#&!4848484848484 ^totot/euhen^ gjrlsmdkkkd` is splited to `#&!4848484848484`, `totot/euhen`, `gjrlsmdkkkd` array. Then array is checked if it has 3 elements, that means that 2 `^` chars were found, text to capture is located in the 2nd element.